# Add class name to an exact element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

There are 7 links in one div and 7 divs in another. Example https://jsfiddle.net/tania_poltava/2oqtr9v1/
I want, when the first link is hovered to influent on first img, adding class; and with other links.

im triing to do this - getting the number of hovered link, then looking for the div with classname with such number, and try to add new class.

```
<div class="links">
    <a href="#" class="services__link--1">button1</a>
    <a href="#" class="services__link--2">button2</a>
    <a href="#" class="services__link--3">button3</a>
    <a href="#" class="services__link--4">button4</a>
    <a href="#" class="services__link--5">button5</a>
    <a href="#" class="services__link--6">button6</a>
    <a href="#" class="services__link--7">button7</a>
</div>
<div class="rounds">
    <div class="services__round--1"></div>
    <div class="services__round--2"></div>
    <div class="services__round--3"></div>
    <div class="services__round--4"></div>
    <div class="services__round--5"></div>
    <div class="services__round--6"></div>
    <div class="services__round--7"></div>
</div>


.rounds div {
  background: grey;
  width:40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.services__round--active {
  background: green;
}


jQuery(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function() { 
 var link = $(".links a"); 
 var linkClass = $(link).attr('class');
 var linkNumb = linkClass.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
 var roundClass = "services__round--" + linkNumb;   
 $(link).hover(function(){ 
 var round = $(roundClass).addClass('services__round--active');  
        // check
console.log(linkNumb);
console.log(linkClass);
console.log(roundClass);

})

})
})
```

Comment: Why dont you generally define in CSS that :hover will add the needed styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:** Answer for your code is;

https://jsfiddle.net/g3wjc6tz/

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var link = $(".links a");
    $(link).hover(function() {
      // check
      $('.services__round--active').removeClass('services__round--active')
      var linkClass = $(this).attr('class');
      var linkNumb = linkClass.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
      var roundClass = "services__round--" + linkNumb;
      var round = $('.' + roundClass).addClass('services__round--active');
      console.log(linkNumb);
      console.log(linkClass);
      console.log(roundClass);

    })

  })
})
```

**Not the best** but more simple and proper way to do it: https://jsfiddle.net/g3wjc6tz/1/

Comment: i cant edit html code, so id and new attribute i have to add using js also

Comment: @танятаня okey then use the first one for your stuation, good luck :)